# Proper use of the [bundesliga] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now the excerpt of the tag [bundesliga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bundesliga) says:

> Questions about the Bundesliga, the highest level of football in
>   Germany.

However, the Bundesliga is not just that. In Germany, the Bundesliga stands for country-wide leagues (usually the highest level and often more than one, even football has two). There are about [50 sports](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_h%C3%B6chsten_Sportligen_in_Deutschland) with one or more leagues called Bundesliga and a few more in Austria.

As it now stands it's kind of irritating.. What about the German Handball Bundesliga or Austrian Football Bundesliga? How can we tell them apart with tags?

- Rename it to [football-bundesliga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football-bundesliga) and deal with the countries in the tag wiki? (And maybe create a new [bundesliga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bundesliga) tag later if a question about a non-football Bundesliga occurs)
- Rephrase the tag wiki & excerpt to include all kind of sports as it's supposed to be?
- Or ignore it, because there are no questions about any non-football Bundesliga?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least to me as an English-speaking UK native, "Bundesliga" means the top-level German football league. While other things may use the term "Bundesliga", they're definitely of secondary importance. Some evidence I'm not alone on this:

- [Typing "Bundesliga" into Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bundesliga) gives the football results, not the handball results.
- [bundesliga.com](https://bundesliga.com/) is the football league.
- (English) Wikipedia has the football league at the [main Bundesliga page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesliga) (I acknowledge this is different on the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu%C3%9Fball-Bundesliga), but we're an English language site).

I see this very much the same as [world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-cup): we're fine using a potentially 
ambiguous tag for one meaning where that meaning is much more common than any others.